# Firebase Realtime Database, Security Rules - Check other nodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have an app connected to Firebase. In this app I have several child nodes, including "Users". The structure of Users is as follows:

```
   Users: {
      -uid: {
        -coins
        -email
        -name
        ...
      }
    }
```

By necessity I need that when a user does a certain action, the number of coins is taken, written in another node and subsequently reset by the main node.
However, some users with root permissions are able to change this value (when switching from one node to another). How can I check with a security rule that the newData of the secondary node corresponds to the value of the coins in Users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without seeing the data you're writing, but I think you're looking for something like this:

```
".write": "newData.child('coins').val() == 
           root.child('Users').child($uidOfTheUser).child('coins').val()"
```

So this checks whether the new data in `coins` under the path where this rule exists is the same as the current `coins` value for the `$uidOfTheUser` user. That `$uidOfTheUser` is either going to come from the path where this rules exists, or from the data that is being written. Here again: if you show us more of the actual code, and JSON, that is being written, we can probably help better.